# Premmision error using GCM and Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-messaging

I opened a portable Xamarin.Forms project and tryied to perform a push notification using GcmClient on the Andorid project
I worte this lines on  the main activity:

```
GcmClient.CheckManifest(this)
private void RegisterGCM()
{
      //  GcmClient.CheckDevice(this);
      //  GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);
      // GcmClient.Register(this, notifocationConsts.SENDER_ID);
}
```

And I am recieveing in the GcmClient.CheckManifest(this) Unhandled Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No receiver allowed to receive
>   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND

Would appericate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receiver allowed to receive com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448225/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-receiver-allowed-to-receive-com-goo)

Comment: but this is written in C# in Xamarin forms...

Comment: the permissions and manifest is the same for Android and Xamarin Android

Comment: yes but how can I put this in the application in xamarin forms

Comment: it goes in the Android project